# JQuery UI Accordion not working with multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am having problems identifying the cause JQuery UI Accordion is not working for my code.

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
 var icons = {
  header: "ui-icon-plusthick",
  activeHeader: "ui-icon-minusthick"
 };

 $('#accordion').accordion({
  header:"h3",
  heightStyle: "content", 
  collapsible : true, 
  active : false, 
  icons: icons
 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
 <h3>Resources</h3>
 <div id="bbContentResources">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <p>Item 2</p>
    <p>Item 3</p>
    <p>Item 4</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the problem? What do you mean with "Accordion is not working for my code"?

Comment: The HTML is displaying as is as supposed to display as an accordion

Comment: Now your post has been edited... and code snippet is working

Comment: Thank you! So you only moved the scripts to the top and fixed the issue?

Comment: Apparently there was no issue... However thanks to @Matheus Cuba who edited your script